# Android button width half of available width - Layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have made a layout with imageview and some buttons i want the buttons to have half the available screen width and height.

This is what I have tried, my xml is as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageidid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/1st row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageid"
    >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="row1 col1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="row1 col2" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/2nd row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/1st row"
    >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="row2 col1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="row2 col2" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the output looks like this.

[image]

and I want something like this.(note imageview to take 40% of screen height)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the code you need to achive what you want, you can just change the wight of the views to set the percentage of screen you want the view to take:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/1st row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageid"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="row1 col1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="row1 col2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/2nd row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/1st row"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="row2 col1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="row2 col2" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, notes:

- according to the "hint" nested weights are bad for performance, nevertheless look at the code,
- Fill_parent is deprecated, use match_parent
- Your "image" is not representative of the percentages visually, in any case, it is easy to change,

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/1strow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/row1col1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/row1col2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/2ndrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/row2col1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/row2col2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RelativeLayout isn't doing anything special, so change it to a LinearLayout (leave both width and height attributes as "match_parent" but add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Then for each of your smaller LinearLayouts, add:

```
android:layout_weight=".xx"
```

where xx is the percentage of the large LinearLayout that you want your child layouts to use.

Background reference here, please do make sure to read it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout as a main layout and then use weightsum property of linear layout